# js sort not consistent on multi sort

Tags: javascript, sorting

I get two different resulting sort orders after sorting my array twice using the native sort method in javascript.  I'm sorting by the field 'date' and 'createdAt'.  I would expect to get the same order of **descending** results each time I pass the same array to the algorithm but I get a different resulting order each time. Why is that?  Example below.

```js
const arr = [
    {"id": 0, 
     "date": new Date("2023-06-02T00:00:00.000Z"), 
     "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-05T01:48:37.586Z")
    },
    {
        "id": 1,
        "date": new Date("2023-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T01:31:35.901Z"),
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "date": new Date("2023-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T17:19:14.733Z"),
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "date": new Date("2023-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:10:26.454Z"),
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "date": new Date("2023-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:11:53.192Z"),
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "date": new Date("2023-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:13:13.879Z"),
    },
    {
        "id": 6,
        "date": new Date("2023-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:15:46.841Z"),
    },
    {
        "id": 7,
        "date": new Date("2023-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:16:45.006Z"),
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "date": new Date("2023-06-04T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T17:21:19.906Z"),
    },
    {
        "id": 9,
        "date": new Date("2023-06-04T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:01:39.286Z"),
    },
    {
        "id": 10,
        "date": new Date("2023-06-04T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:09:48.776Z"),
    },
    {
        "id": 11,
        "date": new Date("2023-06-04T00:00:00.000Z"),
        "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:27:45.701Z"),
    }
]

function sortItems(items) {
  return items.toSorted((a, b) => {
    // do comparison
    if (a.date > b.date) {
      return -1
    } else if (a < b.date) {
      return 1
    } else {
      if (a.createdAt > b.createdAt) {
        return -1
      } else if (b.createdAt < b.createdAt) {
        return 1
      } else {
        return 0
      }
    }
  })
}

const sort_1 = sortItems(arr)
console.log(sort_1)
const sort_2 = sortItems(sort_1)
console.log(sort_2)
```

The result is two diffent resulting sort orders.  Why is that?

Comment: `else if (a < b.date) {` should that be `else if (a.date < b.date) {`

Comment: I get the same result both times - just sayin

Comment: Oh, I see ... Chrome gets a different result - seems typical of chrome

Comment: There also appears to be a typo with `b.createdAt < b.createdAt` - I think it should be `a.createdAt < b.createdAt`. @JaromandaX you were correct, thanks - my answer now  deleted.

Comment: @traktor - yeah, didn't spot the second typo until about a second before you posted that comment :p the oddest thing is that with those typos, chrome produces different results for the two sorts compared to firefox which produces the same result each time

Comment: This might not be the point of the question, but your function can be simplified to something like `items.toSorted((a, b) => b.date - a.date || b.createdAt - a.createdAt)`. `Date` objects can be compared numerically, and so should they.

Comment: Everyone's right.  I just typo'd the hell out of this.  What was wrong with me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simplify your code considerably. And make it more reliable and easier to read:

```js
const arr = [{"id": 0,"date": new Date("2023-06-02T00:00:00.000Z"),"createdAt": new Date("2023-06-05T01:48:37.586Z")},
{"id": 1,"date": new Date("2023-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"),"createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T01:31:35.901Z")},
{"id": 2,"date": new Date("2023-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"),"createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T17:19:14.733Z")},
{"id": 3,"date": new Date("2023-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"),"createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:10:26.454Z")},
{"id": 4,"date": new Date("2023-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"),"createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:11:53.192Z")},
{"id": 5,"date": new Date("2023-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"),"createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:13:13.879Z")},
{"id": 6,"date": new Date("2023-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"),"createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:15:46.841Z")},
{"id": 7,"date": new Date("2023-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"),"createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:16:45.006Z")},
{"id": 8,"date": new Date("2023-06-04T00:00:00.000Z"),"createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T17:21:19.906Z")},
{"id": 9,"date": new Date("2023-06-04T00:00:00.000Z"),"createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:01:39.286Z")},
{"id":10,"date": new Date("2023-06-04T00:00:00.000Z"),"createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:09:48.776Z")},
{"id":11,"date": new Date("2023-06-04T00:00:00.000Z"),"createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:27:45.701Z")}];

function byDates(a,b){return b.date-a.date || b.createdAt-a.createdAt;}

const sort_1 = arr.sort(byDates)
console.log(sort_1)
const sort_2 = sort_1.sort(byDates)
console.log(sort_2)
```

The expression after the "or" (`||`) will only come into action if the result of the first part is not equal to `0`.

**Please note:**
Assigning the `arr.sort(byDates)` results to a new variable, or in this case: a new constant, makes very little sense as `Array.prototype.sort()` works "in place". This means that the source array will be changed and only a reference to that same (but re-ordered) array will be returned.

If you want to preserve the original sort order in `arr` you should `Array.prototype.slice()` the array before `.sort()`ing it:

```
const sort_1 = arr.slice().sort(byDates);
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const arr = [{
    "id": 0,
    "date": new Date("2023-06-02T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-05T01:48:37.586Z")
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "date": new Date("2023-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T01:31:35.901Z"),
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "date": new Date("2023-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T17:19:14.733Z"),
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "date": new Date("2023-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:10:26.454Z"),
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "date": new Date("2023-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:11:53.192Z"),
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "date": new Date("2023-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:13:13.879Z"),
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "date": new Date("2023-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:15:46.841Z"),
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "date": new Date("2023-06-03T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:16:45.006Z"),
  },
  {
    "id": 8,
    "date": new Date("2023-06-04T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T17:21:19.906Z"),
  },
  {
    "id": 9,
    "date": new Date("2023-06-04T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:01:39.286Z"),
  },
  {
    "id": 10,
    "date": new Date("2023-06-04T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:09:48.776Z"),
  },
  {
    "id": 11,
    "date": new Date("2023-06-04T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "createdAt": new Date("2023-06-04T21:27:45.701Z"),
  }
];

let dessort = arr.sort((a, b) => {
  return (a.date - b.date) && (a.createdAt - b.createdAt);
});

console.log(dessort);
```